# How do I print the series 1,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,15?

Tags: javascript

I tried something like this, but it's not working.

```
let array = [];
let count = 1;
for(let i = 1; i < 15; i++){
    if(i == count){
        break
    }else{
        array.push(i);
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: What part of it isn't working? I see a few reasons why it wouldn't give you what you are looking for.

Comment: It's not working, what do you mean by?

Comment: `break` stops the loop, i.e. with the current variable values it's never executed past the first condition. Also, please elaborate the task, "_print_" how? How are you getting the series?

Comment: FWIW the pattern is +2, +1, +2, +1, +1, +2, +1, +1, +1... In case this needs to work on values greater than 15.

Comment: @Chris, the pattern is different ..., see below.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing with different words. I was just breaking it down by step, not offset. Your +2, +3, etc, correspond to my increasing sections of +1's. Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need another variable and start with zero and use an index for skipping and incrementing the counter for the next skipped item.

> ```
>     1     3  4     6  7  8    10 11 12 13   15 taken value
>  0     2        5           9             14   skipped     
> +2    +3       +4          +5                  added offset
> ```

```js
let array = [],
    count = 1,
    index = 0,
    i;
    
for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    if (index === i) {
        index += ++count;
        continue;
    }
    array.push(i);
}

console.log(array.join(' '));
```